# MS Flow iterate ";" separated values

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, power-automate

I am using SharePoint online as a platform where I have a custom form which has multiselect dropdown control. I'm saving the values of the control using ";" in the single line of text field.

Now I want to iterate each of the values which are saved in the field using MS Flow and for example if there are 4 values such as "abc;xyz;hi;hello", I then want these values to be inserted in another list with each value being an item (row) with title column.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Initialize variable action initialize an array value.In string function, you could find the split function.

[image]

```
 split('abc;xyz;hi;hello',';')
```

2.Apply to each action and use create item action in it.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can follow below approach:

1. Add **Compose** action and use `split()` function to split the string by `;` and get array of substrings.
2. Then use **Apply to each** action on **Output** of compose action
3. Inside **Apply to each** action create a new item in 2nd list using [Create item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#create-item) action.

**Working flow in action:**

[image]

**Split function formula:**

```
split(outputs('Get_item')?['body/Title'], ';')
```

Where `outputs('Get_item')?['body/Title']` is a column with multiple values separated by `;`

**Input to Flow**:

[image]

**Output - items create in SharePoint list**:

[image]

For more information check below references:

1. [split string and apply for each](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/split-string-and-apply-for-each/td-p/40643)
2. [Split string into array of characters - empty delimiter not working](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Split-string-into-array-of-characters-empty-delimiter-not/td-p/189153)